# Javascript plugin error handling

Tags: javascript, error-handling, frameworks, error-reporting

I'm creating a javascript framework for other to use on their web page. The framework will essentially do some analytics reporting, so it is not critical to the page to render.

Right now, i put everything in try catch block to ensure that anything that might fail in my code would not prevent the page from rendering.

What i'd like to do though, is to know about those potential errors. So i'm wondering what is considered a good approach in this case. I could use something like rollbar to log the errors to a server, but i wonder about potential conflict with the code of the page.